# Which version of the JSON-RPC does Bitcoin use?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

Which version of the JSON-RPC protocol does Bitcoin use? 1.0 or 2.0? (This question is asked, but that was almost 3 years ago. [link](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/which-version-of-the-json-rpc-protocol-does-bitcoin-use))

If try to use version 2.0 all works well `curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://bitcasino:qwerty@127.0.0.1:8332/`
But named parameters are not supported (or I dont know right parameter names).

Also I fount in bitcoind repo file with declared json-rpc error codes: [link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bitcoinrpc.h). Codes named as `Standard JSON-RPC 2.0 errors` Is it metioned `parts, that not specified in 1.0`?

So what is the official position now? Still 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.0, but with a couple of 2.0 features:

"Batch" calls are supported.

And the 2.0 error semantics are used.

Passing named parameters is not supported.  "Patches welcome" if you want to [add full 2.0 support](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2960).